# ¿Porque no logro darle tamaño a mis iconos?

Tags: html, css, responsive, mediaqueries

No se que estoy haciendo mal

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

como pueden ver por mas que le doy tamaño ya sea con width o con font-size siguen igual pero si le doy tamaño con height si se ven cambios pero lucen deformes. aqui el css

```
@media (min-width: 300px) and (max-width: 500px) {
 .contact-us h5,
      .social-media a {
        margin-bottom: 1rem;
        
      }
      
      .social-media-icon{
        display: inline-flex;
        margin-left: 8px;
        border: 1px solid #fff;
        border-radius: 50%;
        text-align: center;
        color: #ffffff;
        vertical-align: middle;
        width: 35px;
        height: 35px;
        font-size: 38px;
       
      }

      .social-media-icon i{
        font-size: 20px;
        
    }}
```

aqui el html

```
<div class="contact-us">
<h2 class="brand">Direccion Oficina </h2>
                                
<h5 class="fuente-direccion"><br>Diagonal 13 Transversal sexta.<br>Avenida Circunvalar <br>Florencia, Caquetá</h5>
                            
<h2 class="brand">Mas Informacion </h2>
 <h5 class="fuente-direccion"><br>3212546362<br>3212547562<br>funeralesebenezerp@gmail.com</h5>
  </div>
    <div class="social-media">
    <a href="https://web.facebook.com/funeralesebenzer" class="social-media-icon">
        <i class='bx bxl-facebook'></i>
          </a>
    <a href="https://wa.me/3212547562" class="social-media-icon">
     <i class='bx bxl-whatsapp'></i>
 </a>
  <a href="https://www.instagram.com/funeralesebenezer01/?hl=es" class="social-media-icon">
   <i class='bx bxl-instagram' ></i>
    </a>
     </div>
```

por mas que de tamaños no logro darle forma. muchas gracias

Comment: Por que estas accediendo a la clase del contenedor y no a la clase del icono.

Comment: @AntonioGalicia no entiendo. pues en el css se ve que los cambios se los estoy haciendo al icono no? en este caso .social-media-icon muchas gracias amigo

Comment: @mauricio sería bueno si nos dieras el código necesario para poder reproducir tu problema. Si el código es grande, puedes adjuntarlo en https://codepen.io/ y compartirnos el enlace.

Comment: Intenta hacerlo directo con la clase del icono **bxl-whatsapp** y con width y heigth, ya que posiblemente exista un conflicto de referencia, o indicale desde el contenedor padre **.social-media > i**. Verifica también si no tiene clases de configuración, por ejemplo yo uso **font awesome** y para indicar el tamaño del icono se establece con una clase **fa-2x o 3x, etc**.

Comment: @Cris223511.dev https://codepen.io/Incognito12345678/pen/zYJGvOb

Comment: @Cris223511.dev por alguna razon no aparecen los iconos y puse toda el footer en el html . lo siento